# Angular Event window:scroll not Firering (Advanced Layout)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The problem is that the event get fired on some components but not on other components, for instance it fire as soon as i route on all other components except the Landing component. these are my codes bellow.

```
<-- Main Component -->
<div class="body-scroller">
    <app-nav></app-nav>
    <div class="body-wrapper">
        <div class="main-wrapper">
            <div class="main-content">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>  // LandingComponent and Other Components rendered here
            </div>
            <app-footer></app-footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<-- Landing Page Component -->
    <div class="landing-page-content">
    ....
    </div
    <div class="home-content">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>  // HomeComponent rendered here
    </div>


<-- Routing.ts -->
{
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'landing-page',
                component: LandingPageComponent,
                children: [
                    { 
                    path: '', 
                    redirectTo: 'home',
                    pathMatch: 'full' },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: HomeComponent,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'signup',
                component: SignupComponent
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'about',
        component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'about',
                component: AboutComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'contact',
                component: ContactComponent
            },
        ]
}
```

what is causing the event to not firering on landing component ?

Answer (score 0):

Why `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on your Landing Page Component.

You must use one instance of router-outlet.

Comment: is it a problem ? even if i remove `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`  in landing component it doesn't fire at all which means it does not fire in landing page component and its children

Answer (score 0):

Use one router-outlet only. All the components are rendered in a single router-outlet container so there is no need to use it twice.

Comment: But i have some nested children routes that needs to routed under some component!